# SPD WorkFlow Error After Column Deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a workflow which is still working fine but when I click the workflow to check the history log.  It gives this error:

"Sorry, Something Went Wrong.. We can't find that Workflow. Completed instances are automatically cleaned up after 30 days" [image]

I have replicated the error in the new list.  I had a few extra columns which were used in the workflow but **subsequently were deleted from the list**.
 Workflow references for the fields were removed/republished and you get this error. 
What I have tried already:

1. Removing the workflow from the list completely and reactivate/attaching
2. Recreated the deleted columns
3. Recreating the workflow (copy/paste)

I do not know how to fix this?  Any guidance would be much appreciate.

Comment: The workflow history you are trying to view was deleted workflow one?

Comment: I can't be as I can reached the history list via url...very strange when you delete a column previously used in the WF this is when this error comes.

Comment: When you remove a workflow it will delete the associated workflow column but the workflow history still have those records for 30 days.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should delete all the records from the history list ?

Comment: I am giving you the information how it works when you delete workflow. Can you explain further what you want to fix here?

Comment: When I click the workflow status on the list I should see the history logs but instead I get this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61382/discussion-between-venkat-konjeti-and-sharepointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue by delete all the items from the History List including from the Recycle Bin (it seem that the History List or Workflow somehow maintain a reference to delete columns which was creating this issue).

In one of my test tenants, I had to wait for about 24 hours after deleting items from the history list to get this fixed.